# Trying to display two different tables of data from the same model on the same view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am trying to display the data from a single model as two differently filtered tables in the same view page using MVC.

I can get the first table to work perfectly, but the second table filters the already filtered data from the first table.

so example raw data is something like

bob, 10, london
bill, 12, Paris
bob, 10, New York

I want a table of

bill, 12
bob, 10

and a separate table of
London
Paris
New York

But what I get is a second table of 
London
Paris

The code for the first table goes like

```
  <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Select(p => new { p.PlayerId, p.Position, p.Name, p.RankScore, p.CompsPlayed }).OrderBy(p=>p.Position).Distinct())
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Position)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="PlayerResults" asp-route-playerid="@item.PlayerId"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</a>
                </td>

                <td class="text-center">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlayerId)
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RankScore)
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompsPlayed)
                </td>

            </tr>
    }
        </tbody>
```

The second table goes like

```
            @foreach (var item in Model.Select(c => new { c.Comp, c.CompID, c.Players, c.Old }).Where(o => o.Old == false).Distinct())
        {
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="CompResults" asp-route-id="@item.CompID"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comp)</a>
                </td>

                <td class="text-center">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CompID)
                </td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Players)
                </td>

            </tr>
    }
        </tbody>
```

so I am pretty sure that the distinct from the first filtering is sticking for the second filtering.

Any suggestions how to reset in between the two tables?

Or a better way of getting the data in there.

I know that it would be better to move to another view..but that's not what the boss wants

Comment: First thing I would try to make sure is to comment out the first foreach altogether and see what happens.... Second I would declare one variable per foreach to hold the resuld of the Linq expression.  Something like var query1 =  Model.Select(p =............ and then the same for the second query like var query2= ...... and then do the foreach using the variables created like foreach(var item in query1) it will make it easier to debug the issue.

Comment: Also you say that "distinct from the first query is sticking to the second" but you also have a Distinct call on the scond query

Comment: You could create 2 properties on the model that hold your tables of data and then reference those in the view separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple working demo , you could refer to and make the modification on your code:

*Model*

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Position { get; set; }
}
```

*View*

```
@model IEnumerable<Demo1.Models.User>

<h2>Table1</h2>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FullName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.OrderBy(p=>p.Position).Select(p => new { p.FullName, p.Age}).Distinct())
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FullName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>

<h2>Table2</h2>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Position)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Select(p => new { p.Position }).Distinct())
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Position)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

*Result*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Different ways to achieve

1. View Model
2. View Bag
3. View Data
4. Temp Data
5. Session
6. Dynamic
7. Tuples
8. Render Action
9. JSON
10. Navigation Properties